# Lenovo Thinkpad LED Blinking after waking from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, thinkpad, acpi

I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad, "sometimes" after I wake the laptop from suspend both of its LEDs starts blinking, I can fix the issue by putting the laptop in sleep mode and wake it again (sometimes I have to do it more that of one time).

I know that I can reset their status from "blinking" to "on" using:

```
echo 0 on | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/led
```

Is there any specific reason for this? as I can remember a blinking LED was the indicator of something has happened to the system.
And how can I fix the blinking automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd as its init system, we can write a simple script which resets the LED status each time systems wakes from a suspend.

Create a file here:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

Name it whatever you want, e.g: led. then make the file executable:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/led
```

After that write these lines into the file using your desired editor:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "suspend" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre) /bin/true ;;
        post) /bin/echo 0 on > /proc/acpi/ibm/led ;;
    esac
fi
```

It says if the event is a "suspend" (e.g: not a "hibernate") and we are in "post" mode (waking from not going into) write the `0 on` in `/proc/acpi/ibm/led` which resets the LED.